# Notation used within "Prime ideal structure in commutative rings" by M. Hochster

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, notation

I was reading through [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X.pdf) paper and I came across some rather confusing notation in the proof of Theorem 4. It says

> **Proof.** ...$Y$ is finite, and it is clear that the image of the restriction of any element of $[b_1,b_2]$ to $d(b_1)\cup d(b_2)$ is the same as the image of its restriction to $Y$. Thus, we need only find $c\in I=(b_1,b_2)\cap[b_1,b_2]$ such that $c$ does not vanish on $Y$...

My question is what is the $[b_1,b_2]$ notation? My familiarity with its notation is as the Lie bracket, or perhaps the commutator. But neither of which make sense here since we want $I$ to be an ideal. Online searches have also yielded no help.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234678/what-does-the-notation-b-1-b-2-in-m-hochsters-prime-ideal-structure-in-co

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response!

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer, since *it is* an answer, not just a comment? You can also make it CW if you like.

Comment: @EricWofsey Regarding the phrase *some statements that aren't quite right* can you comment on the extent and severity?  I could not find any collected errata online, and I'm hoping one can at least say all the results are right modulo some typos. It looks like a fascinating paper I'd like to read if I ever get time...

Comment: @AVPNeelam When it comes to titles, more specific is better for other people looking for the same answer to your question!  I've edited it to improve its chances of being helpful in the future.  Without mentioning the title of the paper or its author in text, you left it completely invisible for people searching using those terms.

Comment: Another tip here is to use the name of the paper in the link (or at least somewhere in the post)- one unfortunate reality of the internet is sometimes links change or move, and it's not always easy to figure out where a link used to be pointed once that has happened.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Well ideally I would like to just mark this question as a duplicate of that one.  Unfortunately it doesn't let you do that between MSE and MO.

Comment: @rschwieb: It's been about a decade since I read the paper closely but my recollection is that all the main theorems are fine but the proofs often have a lot of misstatements and it took me a lot of work reading it to fill everything in correctly.  Nothing especially serious, but a signficantly higher density of errors than you find in a typical paper.